# Is a dayless, moonlit, icy world possible?

Tags: internal-consistency, planets, moons, day-night

I am seeking to temporarily trap my protagonists on a wasteland. The kind I wanted to create was an icy planet that doesn't experience day or night, just a constant state of moonlight. I suppose the planet would need an atmosphere to create the winds that produce a "drifting snow" effect. I wanted to know if this was scientifically possible. Are there some other laws a planet like this must obey? Would it be better to classify this as an asteroid or comet?

Comment: If the planet orbits a star, then there must be some sort of daylight, I would think.

Comment: Do these conditions have to exist on the entire planet, or is it ok if there's a large area that qualifies, like the dark side of a tidally-locked planet?

Comment: Thank you guys so much for your help on this! I actually wasn't expecting this much. I'm going to weigh around the options presented and see which would provide the deadliest situation.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of making the planet night everywhere (which isn't possible and also have moonlight), but what you could do is have the planet's day be equal to its year so one half the planet is never in the sun. Then have two or three orbiting moons which could provide a mostly-constant moonlight in the dark area.

Depending on how your trapped people can move, you may have to be creative with geography to prevent them from going to the other side of the planet. For example, you could have tall, treacherous mountains like Mt Everest where they can't realistically go over and could also have oceans to prevent walking to the other side.

I don't know what the effect of having one side always night and one side always light would be on the weather cycles, but this should at least give you a good starting point.

Comment: This is often called a "tidally-locked" planet.

Comment: I think a tidally locked planet is the most practical solution. Species adapted to live on the dark side would probably die if exposed to direct sunlight, no artificial barrier is needed to stop them from going to fast but painful death by radiation. Now just make them eat by sucking blood from domesticated animals....

Answer (score 2):

Having a planet in constant 'night' isn't hard. Uranus, for example, sees the sun as a bright star, it doesn't get anywhere near enough in the way of sunlight for us (from our Goldilocks zone perspective) to call it 'day'

**Edit for more numbers!**
The amount of energy delivered to the surface of Uranus by the sun is 3.7 W\m<sup>2</sup>. The amount of energy delivered to the surface of the earth by a full moon is 6.8 W\m<sup>2</sup>, a little over double that. That means that the difference at that distance between day and night is less than the difference between a night with a full moon and a night with no moon on earth.

The issue is that these planets *also* can't have moonlight in the traditional sense, as that's reflected sunlight. If the sun is dim enough that it can be considered night all the time, not enough light will bounce off the moon to illuminate the planet.

A moon can, however, radiate in other ways.

If the moon has a very high (likely artificially so) incidence of heavy radioactive isotopes, it will heat up, and possibly remain hot for a long time. Once your moon is glowing hot, you can have a 'dark' planet, with no real day, illuminated only by the ruddy glow of a slowly decaying moon.

This could also add another level of peril to your world. If whatever formed the moon has irradiated the surface of the world, then your intrepid protagonists are in for what the kids these days call a Bad Time.

In order to have constant moonlight, you need a series of moons. The minimum number of satellites needed for global coverage (ie any point on the planet can see a satellite (ignoring terrain) is four. If the planet was once populated by an alien race that wanted a planetwide <s>subjugation</s> defence network, then they may have built four <s>small moons</s> battlestations. As the <s>small moons</s> battlestations got old the power source for their giant <s>Death Laser</s> spotlight might have  <s>been destroyed by the rebellion</s> melted down, leading to four brightly glowing orbital balls of metal.

And further hazards for your protagonists.

Comment: Uranus isn't anything like night.

Comment: @lorenpechtel Certainly isn't anything like day. A brightly lit night, perhaps, but not day as I'd recognise it.

Comment: Remember the Pluto Time photos?  Pluto is a lot farther out than Uranus.  https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/plutotime/  That's not night.

Comment: @LorenPechtel: When you're using a high gain camera to gather the light reflected from an entire planet it's a much different scenario to actually being on the planet looking around with your human eyes. I'd call a planet that gets less sunlight then the Earth does moonlight fairly 'night-y', and everything past Jupiter gets just that.

Answer (score 1):

A planet who's orbit is highly inclined to the plane of the ecliptic (such as Uranus) will have one hemisphere in "night" for half of its orbit. 
[image]

Any moons orbiting the planet will have a similar "day/night" cycle. In this case, so long as the protagonists are confined by plot device to the night half of the planet or moon, then they will be in the sort of wasteland you envision.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, lose the star altogether and make it a **[rogue planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rogue_planet)**.

A rogue planet is not bound to any star or system and can spend billions of years travelling in the emptiness of space. The conditions do not have to be inhospitable either - there are some theories that such planets may be warm enough to stay above the melting point of water and even support life. You can make it easily a bit colder to make it all frozen over but with still some semblance of weather, perhaps triggered by volcanic eruptions and other internal phenomena rather than outside events.

Answer (score 0):

Would it meet your requirement if the sun appears very dim? Your world could be in a more distant orbit than Earth, around a smaller and less luminous sun. If the composition is very icy, you need something to smash the surface layer into pieces that look like snow. Relatively frequent asteroids? Tectonic grinding?

Such a world would have a thin and unbreathable atmosphere.

Regarding the the second part of your question, the dividing line between a planet and a [dwarf planet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dwarf_planet) is one of [definitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IAU_definition_of_planet). There were complaints when Pluto was "demoted." An asteroid or kuiper belt object may be close to planet-sized.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, although it will not be stable in the long term.

You need to add a brown dwarf to your star system.  It's glowing but in the infrared, this will still look like night.

Your planet is in the L2 point of the star/brown dwarf system--thus in a permanent shadow from it.  Moons of either the dwarf or of the planet itself are outside the shadow, though, and thus get sunlight.

Sorry, but I don't know enough of planetary physics to see if the dwarf can cast a big enough shadow, though. Unless you're going fairly hard science that probably doesn't matter, though.

Note that even if the shadow is too small it might serve your purposes--if the planet is tidally locked to the star you could have a region of perpetual night on the day side of the planet.  If they didn't have a choice of where to land, or if the rest of the terrain was unsuitable (say, a waterworld, the only land being the high points around the axis pointing at the star.)

Answer (score 0):

Your planet could be *orbiting a very old and very tiny neutron star*. An old and dense enough neutron star can emit only non-visible light (gamma radiation) and not even very much of that. Now, the surface of your moon can consist lots of luminescent material which emits visible light when being radiated with gamma radiation, which would result in some "pale moonlight" without actual visible star. Since you have an atmosphere it could contain materials that are protecting your astronaut from frying in the gamma radiation, and can even warm up your atmosphere to a level where snow is possible.

Please note, that such a setup is very unlikely (maybe our universe isn't old enough to contain such a very old and very tiny neutron star), but not impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a planet with a constant eclipse. It's not possible in a natural way (at least not one I can think of) which means that the planet is some sort of a terraforming experiment gone terribly wrong.

Let's say there is a gigantic solar sail on the day side of the planet, blotting out the sun as Persian arrows in "300". It does not orbit the planet, but does not fall down either, using a part of the harnessed energy in order to stay in place, some thousands of miles above the ground.

There is also a big moon, similar to ours, so the night side is lit by it for one half of each month. During the other half the moon is on the day side and the sail blocks it as well.

This way the planet can be quite close to its sun and the sail may, for example, let in infrared light (or maybe it simply cools itself down by radiating heat). So even if it's constant night the temperatures on the surface do no necessarily have to be close to absolute zero. Especially if you want snow to occur the planet has to have a working hydrologic cycle.